# Tkinter listbox widget selection disappears when I double click or highlight text in entry widget

Tags: tkinter, listbox, tkinter-entry

I have a multi-selection Listbox in Tkinter and an entry box which is serving as a search bar for the items within my Listbox.  When I scroll through the Listbox and make a few selections, then click up in the entry widget twice or highlight text in the entry widget, I lose all my selections.  Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: What OS are you using? Can you please post some of your code? We can't debug something that we can't see

Comment: Set `exportselection=0` when creating the `Listbox`.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer relatively fast elsewhere, but didn't see as much info on this topic here, so I figured I'd just post the answer.

This solves the problem:

```
lb.configure(exportselection=False)
```